# Lua with Cocos2D and Box2D giving compile error

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, lua, box2d

I have successfully added Lua to a default Xcode template project by following the process described by [this very helpful post](http://blog.stokedsoftware.com/blog/2012/02/05/scripting-ios-games-with-lua-part-ii/), and got the "Hello, world." text printing.

However, when I try to add Lua to my existing Cocos2D/Box2d project, following exactly the same process, I get a compile error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "luaL_newstate()", referenced from
> ...

My search results on this error refer to one of these possible problems, which I think are OK in my case:

- The target's Build Phases -> Compile Sources - but the same Lua.c files are in both the default template project and my Cocos2D/Box2d project
- I set the header search paths of the default project to match those in the Cocos2D/Box2d project, and the template still compiles fine.
- All the frameworks used by the template project are also in my Cocos2D/Box2d project.

What am I missing?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this integration recently, and the problem that you have there is that the Lua files are written in C, and Box2D is C++.

You will need to wrap the Lua includes like that:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
#endif
```

That should fix the issues, if not post a comment with the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is fantastic, it works perfectly now.  You have saved me a lot of frustration.